# How can a number be transformed into the form of an exponent with a specified base plus or minus a number?

Tags: numerical-integration

This number is:

```
9631218335423173696015738454064712512625486454282845268288357683278517\
4664461287537804846201905350278880351665383273421210406896920475128576\
4221918179043624419894139984279754512017898273159626328827668380262481\
2208650177312678026009153751831792643806511654213677735639479033914667\
6855708979226348173410849338514606325830049576416536529554633780885267\
3629710735621386935094923561594142327134318905856137785813985574356271\
6799186944470152944816918493419174323465595015026833030825915850745767\
8696308503954644628109504872366923085654833908790992275376288406060765\
9880382812905450025751549153093939827557015748607
```

Is there a way in Mathematica to automatically convert it into the form of an exponent plus or minus a constant (with an integer base and an integer exponent)?

like A=B^ x ±C

Comment: **automatically convert it into the form of an exponent plus or minus a constant (with an integer base and an integer exponent)?** what would this expression look like using normal algebra notation and symbols?

Comment: There are an infinity of answers. Here is one example :  2^2023 - 1

Comment: @Daniel Huber How is this calculated?

Comment: @Nasser like A=B^ x ±C

Comment: …Hint: `Log`, `Round`

Comment: Say n is your number, then to get `2^2023 - 1`: the power is: `t = Round[Log[2, n]]; 2^t` and the constant: `n - 2^t`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
a = 963121833542317369601573845406471251262548645428284526828835768327\
8517466446128753780484620190535027888035166538327342121040689692047512\
8576422191817904362441989413998427975451201789827315962632882766838026\
2481220865017731267802600915375183179264380651165421367773563947903391\
4667685570897922634817341084933851460632583004957641653652955463378088\
5267362971073562138693509492356159414232713431890585613778581398557435\
6271679918694447015294481691849341917432346559501502683303082591585074\
5767869630850395464462810950487236692308565483390879099227537628840606\
07659880382812905450025751549153093939827557015748607;
```

The following code finds values of `n` and `b` to minimise `Abs[a-b^n]`

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000},
 MinimalBy[
  Table[Module[{b = Round[a^(1/n)]}, {n, b, Abs[a - b^n]}], {n, 2, 
    Ceiling[Log[a]/Log[2]]}]
  , Last]
 ]
(* {{7, 
  99464647281957328431076449629364168020091230159469543488092795378631\
8994025066751066112, 1}, {17, 664613997892457936451903530140172288, 
  1}, {119, 131072, 1}, {289, 128, 1}, {2023, 2, 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

> A=B^ x ±C

If I understand you right, in the above `A` is the number `n` you showed. And you want to find 3 numbers, `B,x,c` such that `B` and `x` are integers, where $n=B^x+c$ or $n=B^x-c$.

This finds such solutions. In this case `c` is Rational but `B` and `x` are integers even though the command uses `Rationals` domain (using Integer domain does not give solution).

Here are 5 solutions.

```
n = 963121833542317369601573845406471251262548645428284526828835768327\
8517466446128753780484620190535027888035166538327342121040689692047512\
8576422191817904362441989413998427975451201789827315962632882766838026\
2481220865017731267802600915375183179264380651165421367773563947903391\
4667685570897922634817341084933851460632583004957641653652955463378088\
5267362971073562138693509492356159414232713431890585613778581398557435\
6271679918694447015294481691849341917432346559501502683303082591585074\
5767869630850395464462810950487236692308565483390879099227537628840606\
07659880382812905450025751549153093939827557015748607;

eq=n==b^x+c;
sol=FindInstance[eq,{b,x,c},Rationals,5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To verify

```
eq /. sol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If this is not what you meant, let me know so I can delete this answer.